# Oracle 6i reports with graphical components

Tags: oracleforms, oraclereports

How to use graphical components in `64bit` OS with help of `Oracle 6i reports`. In `32bit` machines I am able to run graphs through forms. While using the same report in `64bit` machines I am getting the below error,

`gobat60.exe has stopped working`

I Will appreciate if someone can suggest me a workaround for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since Orace Reports 6i was desupported 10 years ago, your best bet is probably to set up a virtual machine running a 32bit OS.

Comment: You should use procmon (from sysinternals) to get more details on which the process crashes.

Comment: @ammoQ, Good point. That is the way I also thinking. Is there any possiblity for displaying graphics with any third party tools?